# How to use Google Toolbox for Mac for UI unit testing

Tags: cocoa, user-interface

Can u pls show a good example on how to use Google Toolbox for Mac for UI unit testing. 
And every time do i need to have a master image to compare with.
Can i use it for testing whether pressing a button has called the right action??
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but GTM uses it's UI unit testing to test itself. You may want to look at the test code included with GTM for good examples of using it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so can't i use GTM for my app's UI unit testing?

Comment: Yes you can. A good example of GTM doing UI image based unit testing is here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/AppKit/GTMFadeTruncatingTextFieldCellTest.m


and using state based testing is here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/AppKit/GTMLargeTypeWindowTest.m

Answer (score 0):

A very visual tutorial here :

http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2009/02/19/how-to-create-an-iphone-project-in-xcode-that-can-run-unit-tests/

Vincent.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, but i need GTM for UI unit testing. And its one of the features of GTM . And that tutorial deals with iphone unit testing.